# binding ZK with EMF (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, bind, zk, emf

I'm working on a ZK project and I have a third-party domain model based on EMF.
I need to find a way to bind the ZK view with the EMF model.and I didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMF is a code generation framework.
From their website :

> Three levels of code generation are supported:
>   **Model** - provides Java interfaces and implementation classes for all the classes in the model, plus a factory and package (meta data) implementation class.
>   **Adapters** - generates implementation classes (called ItemProviders) that adapt the model classes for editing and display.
>   **Editor** - produces a properly structured editor that conforms to the recommended style for Eclipse EMF model editors and serves as a starting point from which to start customizing.

Next is the server layer you need to implement, so you can insert/save/update/delete your items.

Next is just using the generated classes in ZK.
The zul just need getters/setters from your generated objects. [Those are generated by EMF, as you can see in this tutorial.](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.emf.doc%2Ftutorials%2Fclibmod%2Fclibmod.html)
The ViewModel/Controller need services to load/save your objects.

To remind, ZK it's **only a GUI framework**, it don't matter what model/persistency you use.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to find a way to bind the value of the attributes with other things than properties like methods. because the EObject in EMF don't really act like a POJO or a Bean.

Comment: With `@load` you could use `vm.attribute` or `vm.getAttribute()`.  The zul is normal EL expressions: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html

Comment: Thank you for your help it work for me when I use the `@load` but inot with `@save` if I use for example  `@save(vm.writeMethod())`                                                         I got this       `org.zkoss.zel.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'callMethod' not found on type viewModel.VmBidon
 at org.zkoss.zel.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:442)`

Comment: I know, I'm searching a solution for that.

Comment: how is the syntax for the setters generated by emf?

Comment: actually even with a setter from a simple bean object it doesn't work. ZK still searching for the setter of the `writeMethod()`

Comment: yes but your method is called `setWriteMethod` or something else?

Comment: my method is just called `writeMethod()` actually it's just an example.and  if i want to work with EMF as a model layer i can't use getters and setters